# Http requests gmail api

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, gmail-api

I spent most of the day trying to figure out how to use the gmail api with node.js. I followed the QuickStart guide on google’s website and was pretty quickly able to use the api. It looked like there was 2 ways to do the api requests. One way was in this format:

```
function listLabels(auth) {
    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
    gmail.users.labels.list({
        userId: 'me',
  }, (err, res) => {
     //do whatever here 
  });
}
```

It looked like it could also be used by doing a request like

```
const https = require('https');

https.get('https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/email@gmail.com/messages', (resp) => {//whatever code in here}
```

I was able to figure out how to authenticate and use the first way of doing it. The QuickStart guide makes it pretty easy. I haven’t been able to do it the second way with just urls. Does anyone know how to do it? Even though I will most likely use the first way, I would like to know how to do it the other way.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? The script using googleapis uses the method of Users.labels: list in Gmail API. On the other hand, the script using https.get uses the method of Users.messages: list in Gmail API. So I cannot understand about your goal. Can you explain about your goal in your question?

Comment: Are you using the access token? 
Basically you need to authenticate your HTTPS request to use the API, in the fist example the library does all of that for you already. And in the second option it seems as you are not actually using the OAuth2 flow. Could you confirm if you are actually using the correct token?

Comment: @Raserhin No, I’m not using the access token. I’m not sure how.

Comment: @Tanaike My goal is to use the gmail api through http requests in url form. It looks like it’s possible from the documentation. The specifics of what the two examples do don’t matter. I just want to figure out how to use the api I’m general.

Comment: Of course it's possible! you can just send HTTP request. But you actually need to authenticate yourself to the API. You need to get a token for your user and scopes. I would strongly recommend to use [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). In there you will see all the steps you need to take before sending a HTTP get request. Choosing scopes, getting access token and then doing the final HTTP request.
I still would recommend you to use the library, it makes all the stuff very straightforward.

Comment: I'm looking at OAuth 2.0 playground and things are starting to make more sense. What do I put in the url for userid?

Comment: Glad it helped you out. 
UserId is the mail of the user that you want to retrieve the labels from. In this case using `me` is an special keyword to refer to the account you have used to log in the OAuth Consent screen. 
I will post the  comment as an answer so other people may benefit from it. If you still have more doubts about the API go ahead and post another question to seek help over there and control this comment section. If you think this answer your posted question you can accept and if not please let me know to improve my question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to authenticate your HTTPS request to use the API, in the fist example the library does all of that for you already. And in the second option it seems as you are not actually using the OAuth2 flow.

You can just send HTTP request but you actually need to authenticate yourself to the API. You need to get a token for your user and scopes. I would strongly recommend to use [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). In there you will see all the steps you need to take before sending a HTTP `GET` request directly to the endpoint.

Choosing scopes, getting access token and then doing the final HTTP request. I still would recommend you to use the library, it makes all the stuff very straightforward.